# How do I copy values from one integer array into another integer array using only the keyboard to fill them?

Tags: c, arrays, copy, uart

I am trying to store values received from a non-blocking UART protocol. I enter characters from my keyboard and they are stored in an array called buffer that holds the value. I then want to fill a new array called newbuffer using the value from buffer array and then clear the value in buffer array so it is ready to receive another value from the keyboard.

Here is my initialization:

```
uint8_t buffer[2] = {0};            //initialize array for receiving keyboard input
uint8_t newbuffer[256] = {0};       //initialize array to store keyboard input from buffer array
int i = 0;                          //array index variable

  UartHandle.Instance        = USARTx;

  UartHandle.Init.BaudRate   = 9600;
  UartHandle.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_9B;
  UartHandle.Init.StopBits   = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  UartHandle.Init.Parity     = UART_PARITY_EVEN;
  UartHandle.Init.HwFlowCtl  = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  UartHandle.Init.Mode       = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  UartHandle.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
```

**Here is the callback routine after I have entered my first character. I could really use some help with this part!!!**

```
void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
   //Prevent unused argument(s) compilation warning
  UNUSED(huart);

 for (i = 0; i < sizeof(newbuffer); i++)
 {
     newbuffer[i] = buffer[0];                     //put value entered from keyboard into newbuffer array
     memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));            //clear buffer array for next value
     HAL_UART_Receive_IT (&UartHandle, buffer, 1); //call interrupt that handles entering keyboard values
 }
 printf("%d", newbuffer);
}
```

This is the interrupt function for getting keyboard values, in case you need to see that.

```
static HAL_StatusTypeDef UART_Receive_IT(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
  uint16_t *tmp;

  /* Check that a Rx process is ongoing */
  if (huart->RxState == HAL_UART_STATE_BUSY_RX)
  {
    if (huart->Init.WordLength == UART_WORDLENGTH_9B)
    {
      tmp = (uint16_t *) huart->pRxBuffPtr;
      if (huart->Init.Parity == UART_PARITY_NONE)
      {
        *tmp = (uint16_t)(huart->Instance->DR & (uint16_t)0x01FF);
        huart->pRxBuffPtr += 2U;
      }
      else
      {
        *tmp = (uint16_t)(huart->Instance->DR & (uint16_t)0x00FF);
        huart->pRxBuffPtr += 1U;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      if (huart->Init.Parity == UART_PARITY_NONE)
      {
        *huart->pRxBuffPtr++ = (uint8_t)(huart->Instance->DR & (uint8_t)0x00FF);
      }
      else
      {
        *huart->pRxBuffPtr++ = (uint8_t)(huart->Instance->DR & (uint8_t)0x007F);
      }
    }

    if (--huart->RxXferCount == 0U)
    {
      /* Disable the UART Data Register not empty Interrupt */
      __HAL_UART_DISABLE_IT(huart, UART_IT_RXNE);

      /* Disable the UART Parity Error Interrupt */
      __HAL_UART_DISABLE_IT(huart, UART_IT_PE);

      /* Disable the UART Error Interrupt: (Frame error, noise error, overrun error) */
      __HAL_UART_DISABLE_IT(huart, UART_IT_ERR);

      /* Rx process is completed, restore huart->RxState to Ready */
      huart->RxState = HAL_UART_STATE_READY;

#if (USE_HAL_UART_REGISTER_CALLBACKS == 1)
      /*Call registered Rx complete callback*/
      huart->RxCpltCallback(huart);

#else
      /*Call legacy weak Rx complete callback*/
      HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(huart);
#endif /* USE_HAL_UART_REGISTER_CALLBACKS */

      return HAL_OK;
    }

    return HAL_OK;
  }
  else
  {
    return HAL_BUSY;
  }
}
```

*THANKS IN ADVANCE*  :)

Comment: Why do you post HAL library functions?

Comment: @P_J_ For easy reference. I thought it might help to see what the call is doing. Do you know why the values aren't being stored in newbuffer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. The issue was with having the logic in a for loop. Since the size of newbuffer is 256, the program would not exit the for loop unless all of the characters had been entered and newbuffer was full. By taking my logic out of the for loop, the function could complete and return to main to be recalled in the main loop when the next character was entered.

I also added a flag variable so that I can print the string that was entered when the user types the carriage return button.

Receive Callback Routine:

```
void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
     //Prevent unused argument(s) compilation warning
     UNUSED(huart);

     newbuffer[i] = buffer[0]          //put value entered from keyboard into newbuffer array
     if (newbuffer[i] == '\r')         //if user enters a carriage return the input will be flagged and trigger the while loop to print the string
       {
        flag = 1;
       }
     else
       {
        flag = 0;
       }
     memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));                //clear buffer array to receive next keyboard value
     i++;                                              //increment newbuffer index
     HAL_UART_Receive_IT (&UartHandle, buffer, 1);     //call interrupt that handles entering keyboard values
```

Main:

```
int main(void)
{
  HAL_Init();

  /* Configure the system clock to 180 MHz */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* Initialize BSP Led for LED2 */
  BSP_LED_Init(LED2);

  UartHandle.Instance        = USARTx;

  UartHandle.Init.BaudRate   = 9600;
  UartHandle.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_9B;
  UartHandle.Init.StopBits   = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  UartHandle.Init.Parity     = UART_PARITY_EVEN;
  UartHandle.Init.HwFlowCtl  = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  UartHandle.Init.Mode       = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  UartHandle.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&UartHandle) != HAL_OK)
  {
    /* Initialization Error */
    Error_Handler();
  }

  NVIC_SetPriority(USART3_IRQn, (1u << __NVIC_PRIO_BITS) - 5u); //set interrupt priority
  NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART3_IRQn);

                             /*INTERRUPT METHOD*/
  HAL_UART_Receive_IT (&UartHandle, buffer, 1);  //call UART receive interrupt to get keyboard input

  //Infinite loop
  while (1)
  {

     //output a message in Hyperterminal requesting keyboard input
          printf("\n\rEnter your string: ");
         NVIC_DisableIRQ(USART3_IRQn);
          if (flag == 1)
                  {
                     printf("%s", newbuffer);                       //string is printed if user enters a carriage return
                     flag = 0;                                      //reset flag so the interrupt routine can look for another carriage return
                     memset(newbuffer, 0, sizeof(newbuffer));       //clear newbuffer so it is ready to store a new string
                     i = 0;                                         //reset index so newbuffer begins storing its new string starting at newbuffer[0]
                  }
         NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART3_IRQn);
          HAL_Delay (1000);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you realized that you are copying exactly 1 byte in the for loop inside HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback, whereas array buffer is two bytes in size ?

This sentence: `newbuffer[i] = buffer[0];` is just copying the first byte.

If you are reading from the keyboard you are probably getting scan codes. Scan codes are not all one byte, but many of them. Depending on the keys they can be up to three bytes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scancode.

Comment: I only want to copy over one character at a time, so I only need an index of one for the buffer array. I'll change buffer[2] to buffer[1] to save on memory though.